# Assembly x86 call after cmp

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following code to compare numbers and increment a variable if true or false

```
failcheck1:
            mov eax, val1
            add ebx, 4
            cmp eax, 40
            jl failinc1

            mov eax, passes
            inc eax
            mov passes, eax
            jmp failcheck2

failinc1:
            mov eax, fails
            inc eax
            mov fails, eax


failcheck2 :
            mov eax, val2
            add ebx, 4
            cmp eax, 40
            jl failinc2

            mov eax, passes
            inc eax
            mov passes, eax
            jmp failcheck3

failinc2:
            mov eax, fails
            inc eax
            mov fails, eax
```

I have 8 such checks. I was wondering if I create a single failinc and passinc subroutine with **ret** in it how can I call it after **cmp** ?

Comment: Same as always, the function itself has to carefully not destroy the flags before it uses them though

Comment: here is something: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2T2V_7RvB4 - you call subroutines using `call` asm command: `call - ret` pair - google it

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I know that I have to use `call` but my issue is how to call it only if the `cmp eax, 40` is below 40. That is what I am struggling with

Comment: Wait, you want to call conditionally? That wouldn't even really reduce code.. you'd have the same structure as now but with `mov\inc\mov` replaced with `call`. Btw you can `inc fails` directly.

Comment: What I am trying to do is reduce failinc1 to failinc8 (which is 8 separate ones) with a single one that is being called and returns to the address of where it was called. Edit - added failinc2 to show you what my code is. That is repeated 8 times total

Answer (score 2):

Because `EBX` is independantly incrementing, you can replace the 8 `add ebx, 4` by a single addition `add ebx, 4*8`.

You can avoid all of those ugly and time consuming conditional jumps by using the conditional set instruction `setl` (Set On Less).

Because *fails* and *passes* are mutually exclusive, you can defer from calculating the *passes* to the very end. e.g. If processing 8 values gave 3 *fails* then there inevitably have to be 5 *passes* (is 8 minus 3).

```
 xor  ecx, ecx    ;Clear because SETL only operates on a byte
 xor  edx, edx    ;Clear temporary counter of fails

 cmp  val1, 40
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter
 cmp  val2, 40
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter
 cmp  val3, 40
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter
 cmp  val4, 40
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter
 cmp  val5, 40
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter
 cmp  val6, 40
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter
 cmp  val7, 40
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter
 cmp  val8, 40
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter

 add  fails, edx  ;Add temporary counter to actual variable
 sub  edx, 8
 sub  passes, edx ;Add complementary count to other variable (*)

 add  ebx, 4*8
```

---

> I was wondering if I create a single failinc and passinc subroutine with **ret** in it how can I call it after **cmp** ?

Now the subroutine

```
AddTempCount:     ;On input EFLAGS is set from CMP instruction
 setl cl
 add  edx, ecx    ;Conditionally increment temporary counter
 ret
```

can improve the readability a bit.

```
 xor  ecx, ecx    ;Clear because SETL only operates on a byte
 xor  edx, edx    ;Clear temporary counter of fails

 cmp  val1, 40
 call AddTempCount
 cmp  val2, 40
 call AddTempCount
 cmp  val3, 40
 call AddTempCount
 cmp  val4, 40
 call AddTempCount
 cmp  val5, 40
 call AddTempCount
 cmp  val6, 40
 call AddTempCount
 cmp  val7, 40
 call AddTempCount
 cmp  val8, 40
 call AddTempCount

 add  fails, edx  ;Add temporary counter to actual variable
 sub  edx, 8
 sub  passes, edx ;Add complementary count to other variable (*)

 add  ebx, 4*8
```

(*) Subtracting a negative count is the same as adding a positive count.

Answer (score 0):

```
failcheck:
    mov eax, [eax]
    add ebx, 4
    cmp eax, ecx
    jl .L1
    incl passes
    ret
.L1:
    incl fails
    ret

failcheck1:
    lea eax, val1
    mov ecx, 40
    call failcheck

    lea eax, val2
    mov ecx, 40
    call failcheck
```

Comment: Instead of `incl passes`, you may need to use `inc dword passes`, depending on your assembler.